# PHP_EOL not working always with Outlook

Tags: php, email, outlook

Trying to format an email that's being sent via PHP mail.  I'm using PHP_EOL to terminate lines and it works most of the time.

When viewing the email in Outlook, some lines don't end which leads to lines being combined.

```
label: value label: value label: value
```

instead of every other line in the email which is

```
label: value
```

I've viewed the same email in Gmail and it was formatted correctly.  I've tried Googling and looking here for a solution but no luck so far.

Two PHP_EOL's at the end of each line 'works', but then I have an empty line between each line so it doubles the length of the email.

EDIT:
Here's a function that's used to creation six different sections of the plain-text email (6 lines each section).  Two sections have 6&7 combined, three sections have 7&8 combined, and another has no issues.  There are calls to a couple other functions that just spit out text in the format of 'var1, var2, var3' and also 'Property' or 'Property_Comment'.

```
`function buildClubOrder($club, $document){
$order = str_replace('_', ' ', $club) . ' - ' . PHP_EOL;
$order .= 'Dexterity: ' . $document[$club]['Dexterity'] . PHP_EOL;
$option = getSetOption($document[$club]['Std_Set_Make_up']);
$order .= str_replace('_', ' ', $option) . ': ' . $document[$club][$option] . PHP_EOL;
$order .= 'Shaft: ' . $document[$club][getClubOption($document[$club]['Shaft'], 'Shaft')] . PHP_EOL;
$order .= 'Build Instructions: ' . buildInstructions($club, $document) . PHP_EOL;
$order .= 'Duplicate Orders: ' . $document[$club]['Duplicate_orders_'];
return $order;`
```

Example three lines combined output:

Irons -

Dexterity: DATA

Custom Set Make Up: DATA

Shaft: DATA DATA Build Instructions: DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA Duplicate Orders: DATA DATA DATA

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is the line ending used on the machine that is running PHP (the server).  So unless it's a Windows server you won't get Windows line endings in the PHP generated email.

Comment: Thanks Abra.  In efforts to switch out PHP_EOL I've used \n, \r, and \r\n.  When I do that, I get the characters without a line break. Ex: `. '\n'` used instead of `. PHP_EOL`.

Comment: Just curious -Why would PHP_EOL work for terminating most lines but not all?  And why would it work twice when a second PHP_EOL is added when a sole PHP_EOL doesn't?

Comment: Are you using single quotes or double?

Comment: Was using single quotes, thanks.  In testing with double quotes, `"\n"` and `"\r"` create the same issue as PHP_EOL (same lines fine, same problem lines a problem).  When using `"\r\n"`, I get a blank line separating every line (same as double PHP_EOL).

Comment: Are you sending plain text or HTML email? Show the whole code that creates and sends the email.